# remove space between digits of a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a data frame that there are some spaces in one of it's column values(column 'address'). For example:
['2 47, Philiproad, London, uk', '12 4, Northhall, London, uk']

There are thousands of these records in my data. How can I remove spaces betweeb '2' and '47' for example and have following outcome using regular expression:

['247, Philiproad, London, uk', '124, Northhall, London, uk']

Comment: Make sure that you really want to do this. Those digits might be separated for a reason. Eg, '2 47' could be apartment 2 at number 47.

Comment: Thanks, I checked it. Unfortunately the space is entered by users' mistake and should be removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the spaces first with nothing, and then add a space after every comma.
I have tried this as :

```
>>> import re
>>> string1 = '2 47, Philip road, London, uk'
>>> regex = re.compile("(\d )", re.S)
>>> regex.sub(lambda x: x.group()[0].replace(" ", ""), string1)
'247, Philip road, London, uk'
```

Comment: Thanks pissall. I am new to regular expression in Python. I couldn't find regular.sub function in Python 3 and when I changed your codes to re.sub I faced another error. Would you pleas help me to figure out what's wrong. Your output is exactly the same thing that I am after.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I used the same variable I was using in my pc. I have repaired it.

Comment: Thanks so much. It's exactly what I am after :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `regex` :

```
>>>  [re.sub('(?<=\d)+ (?=\d)+', '', ele) for ele in l]
```

This uses the concept of `lookahead` and `lookbehind` in regex.

#driver functions :

```
IN : ['2 47, Philiproad, London, uk', '12 4, Northhall, London, uk']
OUT : ['247, Philiproad, London, uk', '124, Northhall, London, uk']
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edited so `New York` won't turn to `NewYork`**

This should sort out the `address` column (here I assume your dataframe is `df`):

```
def replace_if_num(s):
    no_spaces = s.replace(' ', '')
    if no_spaces.isdigit():
        return no_spaces
    return s

def foo(s):
    ', '.join(map(replace_if_num, s.split(',')))

df['address'] = df['address'].map(foo)
```

Comment: Thanks but it removes all of spaces in my string. There some addresses like 'Northern Philiproad, 67 8'. This function removes all of spaces and returns 'NorthernPhiliproad, 678' that is no desired.

Comment: @user3665906 correct you are. Changed the answer to only remove spaces from numerical strings.

Answer (score 1):

good answers already given, here is an alternative without `lambda` nor `re`:

```
# input list
lst = ['2 47, Philiproad, London, uk', '12 4, Northhall, London, uk']

# remove a space if it exists before the first comma in the element of the lst
result = [a if ' ' not in a.split(',')[0] else a.replace(' ','',1) for a in lst]

print(result)
```

output:

```
['247, Philiproad, London, uk', '124, Northhall, London, uk']
```